# How to find the derivative of a piece-wise function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the derivative of the function at $x=0$
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> e^x + x^3\cos\frac{1}{x}, &x\ne 0,\\
> 1, &x = 0.
> \end{cases}$$

Now isn't this is trivial? Since $f(x)  = 1$ when $x = 0$ so the derivative at this point would be $0$ since it is a constant? Do I have to even compute the derivative for the first expression? But this seems to simple relative to the points offered for this question?

Answer (score 1):

You could only apply that reasoning if the function were constant on an *interval* around $x=0$, which is not the case here.

Comment: MPW, isnt $f(x) = 1$ constant over the real interval? Isn't this is just a straight horizontal line over all the real x-values?

Comment: But it must be *your function* that is constant over an interval of *its domain* to use that logic. Your function isn’t constant over an interval.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^x + x^3\cos\frac{1}{x}, &x\ne 0,\\
1, &x = 0.
\end{cases}$

By definition of derivative: 
$\begin{align}f'(0)=&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\\=&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x+x^3\cos\frac 1x-1}{x}\\=&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3\cos\frac 1x+x+o(x)}{x}\\=&\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2\cos\frac 1x+\frac{o(x)}x)=1\end {align}$

I have used Maclaurin series for $e^x$ which can be written as $e^x=1+x+o(x)$ for small enough $x$.

**Note that** $f(0)=1$, which is a constant (value of the function $f$ at $x=0$). What you want is derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ whose definition is as given above. What it means is that you also need to consider $x$ close to $0$ also to define $f'(0)$ in $\mathbb R$. For example:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\ln(x+1); x\ne 0\\0; x=0\end{cases}$.

Question is what is $f'(0)$ here? According to you: $f(0)=0\implies f'(0)=0$ but then someone may also point out that since $f(x)=0$ at $x=0$, no harm in writing $f(x)=x$, when $x=0$ and therefore, $f'(x)=1$, when $x=0$.

**Both these are wrong** ways of calculating derivative as derivative of $f$ at a point ($x=0$ here) requires $f$ to be *atleast* defined in some neighborhood of $a$ as per definition of $f'(0)$. Using that here, $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\ln (x+1)}{x}=1$ (By L'hospital's rule)

Comment: Hi Koro, thanks for the answer. I have a few questions. You replaced $h$ with $x$ for brevity? So we don't care what happens at point $a$ as long as the limit from either side approach to the same value? Can I also just find the derivative for $e^x$ and use the product rule and chain for the other part?

Comment: Koro so you used, $x$ approaches $0$ can I use $h$ approaches $0$? Why did you use $x$ approaches $0$

Comment: Koro, what about $x^2cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ as x approaches $0$? What about the $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @GoNK: 1) Replacing $h$ with $x$: Yes for brevity. 2) Product rule & Chain rule: You can use that on the function $e^x + x^3\cos\frac{1}{x}$. Note that $f(x)\ne e^x + x^3\cos\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. So for finding $f'(0)$, you have to use definition. 3) What about $\frac 1x$: Note that: $-1 \le \cos\frac 1x\le 1$ and therefore $-x^2 \le x^2\cos\frac 1x\le x^2$. Now apply squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You will need to compute $$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$$ to determine the derivative.  You cannot differentiate solely based on the value of a function at a point, otherwise the derivative of every function would vanish.

Comment: Hi DMcMor, what did you mean why "cannot differentiate solely based on the value of a function at a point", isnt $f'(0)$ doing exactly that? I am finding the derivative at point $0$ right? Many thanks again.

Comment: DMcMor can I just use the product rule for the $x^3$ part?

Comment: @GoNK I mean that just because you know that $f(0) = 1$ doesn't mean you can conclude that $f'(0) = 0$.  You would need $f(x) = 1$ on some interval around $x = 0$.  If you were only interested in computing $f'(x)$ for $x \ne 0$ then yes you can just use the product rule.  But since you are looking for $f'(0)$, and there is no single expression for $f(x)$ on an interval containing $x = 0$, you need to use the definition of derivative.  You also can't just compute $f'(x)$ for $x \ne 0$ and find $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ because that assumes $f'$ is continuous, which is not necessarily true.

Answer (score -1):

The derivative of $e^x+ x^3 cos(1/x)$ is $e^x+ 3x^2 cos(1/x)+ x sin(1/x)$.  This function is NOT differentiable at x= 0.

Comment: Really? Clearly $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: That's easy to say!  What  is the derivative at x= 0?  $f(h)= e^h+ h^3 cos(1/h)$ and $f(-h)= e^{-h}- h^3cos(1/h)$ so $f(h)- f(-h)= e^h- e^{-h)+ 2h^3 cos(1/h)$.  $\frac{f(h)- f(-h)}{h}= \frac{e^h- e^{-h}}{h}+ 2h^2 cos(1/h)$.  Since $e^x$ is differentiable and $2h^2 cos(1/h)$ goes to 0 as x goes to 0, the derivative at x= 0 is 1.  You are right and I was wrong!

Comment: @user247327 You really need to use the _definition_ of the derivative here! _If_ $f'(0)$ exists then it equals $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{2h}$, but the existence of that limit does _not_ imply that $f'(0)$ exists.